# Native method to calculate confidence upper bounds for the mean of a Poisson Distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

Reading about how to calculate confidence intervals for Poisson distributions, one says that if the unknown mean is high you can use the Normal distribution approximation and use $\widehat\lambda\pm c\sqrt{\widehat\lambda/n}$, where $\widehat\lambda$ is the mean of your sample of size $n$ and $c$ is to adjust your coverage. For example, for a 95% confidance interval, you use $c=1.96$. If your unknown mean is not high enough, you then use $\chi^2$ tables.

But, why can't one deduce a formula for confidence intervals without relaying on other distributions? Let's try.

For simplification, I'm focusing on calculating the upper bound of the interval. For the normal approximation, it's $\boxed{f_\mathcal{N}(\widehat\lambda, n, c)=\widehat\lambda+c\sqrt{\widehat\lambda/n}}$.

### Finding the exact upper bound

Given $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ where each $X_i\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ unknown, estimate an upper bound for $\lambda$ with confidence level $p$. Let's call
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\qquad \widehat\lambda=\frac{X}{n}$$

We know that $X\sim\text{Pois}(n\lambda)$. Now we find the $c$ such that:
$$
\Pr\left[X\leq n\lambda+c\sqrt{n\lambda}\right]=p
$$

$\lambda$ and $n$ are unknown but using that expression the probability approaches $p$ depending only on $c$. For example, for $c=2$, the probability approaches $97.5\%$ as $n\lambda$ grows, and for $c=4$, it goes to $\approx 1$ (the blue area isn't actually an area, just an effect of the distribution being discrete)

[image]  [image]

Now, solving the second degree equation on $\sqrt{n\lambda}$ (taking the possitive side of $\pm$, because its negative side yields a negative fraction):

$$X\leq n\lambda+c\sqrt{n\lambda}\ \Longrightarrow\ \sqrt{n\lambda}\geq \frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2+4X}}{2} \Longrightarrow\ \lambda\geq\frac{(-c+\sqrt{c^2+4X})^2}{4n}$$

Taking the lower bound of the inequation and simplifying:

$$
\boxed{f_\text{Pois}(\widehat\lambda, n, c)=\widehat\lambda+\frac{c}{2n}\left(c+\sqrt{c^2+n\widehat\lambda}\right)}
$$

### Comparing $f_\mathcal{N}$ and $f_\text{Pois}$

So, how good is the $f_\mathcal{N}$ approximation? Let's define:

$$
g_n(\widehat\lambda, c) = \frac{f_\mathcal{N}(\widehat\lambda, n, c)}{f_\text{Pois}(\widehat\lambda, n, c)}=\frac{\widehat\lambda+ c\sqrt{\widehat\lambda/n}}{\widehat\lambda+\frac{c}{2n}\left(c+\sqrt{c^2+n\widehat\lambda}\right)}
$$

which is the overestimation ratio of $f_\mathcal{N}$ over $f_\text{Pois}$. It turns out that:
$$
g_n(\widehat\lambda, c) = g_1(n\widehat\lambda, c)\ \Longrightarrow\ g_1(\widehat\lambda, c) = g_n(\widehat\lambda/n, c)
$$

It implies that to analize the overestimation behaviour of $f_\mathcal{N}$, you only need to analize it for samples of size 1 (or in other words, for single Poisson variables), and then scalate the results for bigger sample sizes.

The function $g_1$ looks like that (for $c=1.96$ and $c=4$ respectively):

[image]    [image]

For any $c$, the function starts at $0$ and increases very fast until reaching the maximum value of $1.082954$, and then decreases very slowly, having $1$ as horizontal asymptote. That means that for low values of $\widehat\lambda$, $f_\mathcal{N}$ underestimates $f_\text{Pois}$, a bit later they become equal, then it starts overestimating it until reaching that maximum value of $+8.295\%$, and then they become more and more close to each other as $\widehat\lambda$ increases.

The green vertical lines are the values of $\widehat\lambda$ for each $c$ where $g_1$ reaches that maximum value of $+8.295\%$.

A higher $n$ (a higher sample size) just speeds up that behaviour by a factor of $/n$. For example, for $n=10$, both curves look now like:

[image]    [image]

So given that $f_\mathcal{N}$ always have a worst case of a $+8.295\%$ for some $\widehat\lambda$, isn't it better to just use the exact $f_\text{Pois}$, **or was everything I did totally wrong?**

**NOTE:** Tables of $g_n(\widehat\lambda, c)$ values, for $c=1.96$ and $c=4$. For each $c$, I give two tables, the first one is the overestimation percentage for different $\widehat\lambda$'s (`L`) and $n$'s, and a second table indexed by $\%$ instead (to know the minimum $\widehat\lambda$'s yielding overestimations below each percentage). In both tables, the first column is the sample size, and the other columns the calculated values.

For $c = 1.96$,

```
    |   n\L |       1 |       2 |       5 |      10 |      25 |      50 |     100 |     250 |     500 |    1000 |

    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    |     1 | -41.70% | -24.13% |  -4.60% |   4.06% |   8.13% |   8.03% |   6.87% |   5.03% |   3.80% |   2.81% |

    |     2 | -24.13% |  -8.60% |   4.06% |   7.71% |   8.03% |   6.87% |   5.47% |   3.80% |   2.81% |   2.05% |

    |     5 |  -4.60% |   4.06% |   8.13% |   8.03% |   6.42% |   5.03% |   3.80% |   2.54% |   1.84% |   1.33% |

    |    10 |   4.06% |   7.71% |   8.03% |   6.87% |   5.03% |   3.80% |   2.81% |   1.84% |   1.33% |   0.95% |

    |    25 |   8.13% |   8.03% |   6.42% |   5.03% |   3.45% |   2.54% |   1.84% |   1.19% |   0.85% |   0.61% |

    |    50 |   8.03% |   6.87% |   5.03% |   3.80% |   2.54% |   1.84% |   1.33% |   0.85% |   0.61% |   0.43% |

    |   100 |   6.87% |   5.47% |   3.80% |   2.81% |   1.84% |   1.33% |   0.95% |   0.61% |   0.43% |   0.31% |

    |  1000 |   2.81% |   2.05% |   1.33% |   0.95% |   0.61% |   0.43% |   0.31% |   0.19% |   0.14% |   0.10% |

    | 10000 |   0.95% |   0.68% |   0.43% |   0.31% |   0.19% |   0.14% |   0.10% |   0.06% |   0.04% |   0.03% |



    |   n\% |    +0.00% |    +8.30% |    +5.00% |    +3.00% |    +1.00% |    +0.50% |    +0.10% |

    |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    |     1 |      6.83 |     33.16 |    253.87 |    862.37 |   9016.61 |  37252.68 | 954626.98 |

    |     2 |      3.41 |     16.58 |    126.93 |    431.18 |   4508.31 |  18626.34 | 477313.49 |

    |     5 |      1.37 |      6.63 |     50.77 |    172.47 |   1803.32 |   7450.54 | 190925.40 |

    |    10 |      0.68 |      3.32 |     25.39 |     86.24 |    901.66 |   3725.27 |  95462.70 |

    |    25 |      0.27 |      1.33 |     10.15 |     34.49 |    360.66 |   1490.11 |  38185.08 |

    |    50 |      0.14 |      0.66 |      5.08 |     17.25 |    180.33 |    745.05 |  19092.54 |

    |   100 |      0.07 |      0.33 |      2.54 |      8.62 |     90.17 |    372.53 |   9546.27 |

    |  1000 |      0.01 |      0.03 |      0.25 |      0.86 |      9.02 |     37.25 |    954.63 |

    | 10000 |      0.00 |      0.00 |      0.03 |      0.09 |      0.90 |      3.73 |     95.46 |
```

For $c=4$,

```
    |   n\L |       1 |       2 |       5 |      10 |      25 |      50 |     100 |     250 |     500 |    1000 |

    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    |     1 | -71.01% | -58.58% | -37.09% | -19.68% |  -1.76% |   5.44% |   8.07% |   7.79% |   6.51% |   5.11% |

    |     2 | -58.58% | -42.71% | -19.68% |  -5.28% |   5.44% |   8.07% |   8.08% |   6.51% |   5.11% |   3.87% |

    |     5 | -37.09% | -19.68% |  -1.76% |   5.44% |   8.28% |   7.79% |   6.51% |   4.68% |   3.51% |   2.59% |

    |    10 | -19.68% |  -5.28% |   5.44% |   8.07% |   7.79% |   6.51% |   5.11% |   3.51% |   2.59% |   1.88% |

    |    25 |  -1.76% |   5.44% |   8.28% |   7.79% |   6.05% |   4.68% |   3.51% |   2.34% |   1.69% |   1.22% |

    |    50 |   5.44% |   8.07% |   7.79% |   6.51% |   4.68% |   3.51% |   2.59% |   1.69% |   1.22% |   0.87% |

    |   100 |   8.07% |   8.08% |   6.51% |   5.11% |   3.51% |   2.59% |   1.88% |   1.22% |   0.87% |   0.62% |

    |  1000 |   5.11% |   3.87% |   2.59% |   1.88% |   1.22% |   0.87% |   0.62% |   0.40% |   0.28% |   0.20% |

    | 10000 |   1.88% |   1.35% |   0.87% |   0.62% |   0.40% |   0.28% |   0.20% |   0.13% |   0.09% |   0.06% |



    |   n\% |    +0.00% |    +8.30% |    +5.00% |    +3.00% |    +1.00% |    +0.50% |    +0.10% |

    |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    |     1 |     28.44 |    138.09 |   1057.35 |   3591.70 |  37553.58 | 155154.84 |3975955.77 |

    |     2 |     14.22 |     69.05 |    528.67 |   1795.85 |  18776.79 |  77577.42 |1987977.89 |

    |     5 |      5.69 |     27.62 |    211.47 |    718.34 |   7510.72 |  31030.97 | 795191.15 |

    |    10 |      2.84 |     13.81 |    105.73 |    359.17 |   3755.36 |  15515.48 | 397595.58 |

    |    25 |      1.14 |      5.52 |     42.29 |    143.67 |   1502.14 |   6206.19 | 159038.23 |

    |    50 |      0.57 |      2.76 |     21.15 |     71.83 |    751.07 |   3103.10 |  79519.12 |

    |   100 |      0.28 |      1.38 |     10.57 |     35.92 |    375.54 |   1551.55 |  39759.56 |

    |  1000 |      0.03 |      0.14 |      1.06 |      3.59 |     37.55 |    155.15 |   3975.96 |

    | 10000 |      0.00 |      0.01 |      0.11 |      0.36 |      3.76 |     15.52 |    397.60 |
```

Comment: What's the basis for the claim that t-tables would  be better than z tables for small-population-mean Poisson variables?

Comment: @Glen_b I think it came from a little study I (over)read linked on an comment on this site. Anyway, I can remove the mention to t-tables in the question if that's potentially misleading. What I want to know is if my $f_2$ formula is solid or it's just me naively using random variables, or if it has any potential downside respect to the more traditional methods. Because if $f_2$, deduced by someone with a very basic mathematical background (me), is totally solid for calculating "upper bounds of confidence intervals", it would be weird that there's 0 mentions anywhere about it.

Comment: Id be intetsted to see what that study you mention said - what their evidence was. .... Now *why must    λ be a natural number*?

Comment: @Glen_b because Poisson variables are discrete.

Comment: X is discrete. X is not  λ; the parameter is the population average rate per unit time. Why should it be discrete?

Comment: @Glen_b Ok you are right; I misunderstood the situation. I just thought that since the restriction $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$ doesn't harm (because if $\lfloor\lambda\rfloor\neq\lceil\lambda\rceil$ and $X_1\sim\text{Pois}(\lfloor\lambda\rfloor)$, $X_2\sim\text{Pois}(\lceil\lambda\rceil)$ then $X_1=X_2$), and the variable itself is discrete, I somehow deduced that $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For a start, we know something that does even better: using $\exp(\log(\hat{\lambda}) \pm 1.96 \times 1/\sqrt{x_N})$ as you CI. I.e. the normal approximation works a lot better on the log scale (and you then back-transform). Additionally, we of course know exactly how to calculate an exact confidence interval (see e.g. https://www.statsdirect.com/help/rates/poisson_rate_ci.htm).

Comment: @Glen_b I did a proper rewritting of the question allowing $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.